# React | DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**React display {error} problem.**

So I have this problem with an error I'm trying to make a DOM element, but it doesn't wanna take work, even though it has a value.

- So I made a validator that makes an empty object called **'error'** into an array with two objects, username, and password, they then got strings inside them with the text **"{value} is invalid"**, and if the input field is empty, I want it to display it in the DOM. But it doesn't wanna do it, and here is the code.

The thing that doesn't want to display are these variables **'{errors.password}'**, they're on the end of the last code snippet.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Form from './Form'
export default function App() {

const [ username, setUsername ] = useState("");

const [ password, setPassword ] = useState("");

return (
<>
  <Form
  // Username
  usernameValue={username}
  setUsernameValue={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
  // Password
  passwordValue={password}
  setPasswordValue={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} 
  />
</>);}
```

**Form.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Form({usernameValue, setUsernameValue, passwordValue, setPasswordValue}) {

// Easier to use names
const value = {
    username: usernameValue,
    password: passwordValue,
    errors: {}
};

// Replacement for setState(hook)
const [errors, setError] = useState({});
    
// Validator
function validate() {
    const errors = {};
    if (value.username.trim() === "") // If there is nothing in the field (trim() checks for empty-space and cuts it *normally*)
        errors.username = 'Username is invalid'
    if (value.password.trim() === "")
        errors.password = 'Password is invalid'
    
    // console.log(errors)

    return Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? null : errors; // If errors array is equal to 0 return null, if not, return error
};

// Check for errors
function handleOnSubmit(e) { // e = event
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent reload
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.div').innerHTML)

    // Set errors locally to validate()
    const errors = validate();
    setError({ errors: errors || {} }) // We don't want it to be a null, so we set it to {}, and hook state errors is equal to local errors
    if (errors) return;

    // Call when submitted
    console.log('Submitted')
};

return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
            <input value={value.username} type="text" placeholder="name" onChange={setUsernameValue} />
            <input value={value.password} type="text" placeholder="password" onChange={setPasswordValue} />

            <button type="submit" onClick={validate}>Submit</button>
        </form>
            <div className="div">{errors.username}</div>
            <div className="div">{errors.password}</div>
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Why not return `errors` in `validate`? You are setting it to `{}` anyway in the handler.

Comment: Well, the main reason is that my handler is connected to my onSubmit in the form element, and so it verifies if there are any errors left, if not then it can submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Your error state is

```
const [errors, setError] = useState({});
```

and you access your errors as `error.username` and `error.password`

```
<div className="div">{errors.username}</div>
<div className="div">{errors.password}</div>
```

But when you set the error state you nest the error object into an `{ error: {...} }` property

```
setError({ errors: errors || {} });
```

## Solution

Simply update your state with the errors object itself.

```
setError(errors);
```

[image: Edit stoic-https-f4vyc]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Drew, it solved the problem in an instant :) Also thanks Cehhiro, I can see how you can just move all of it into the validator, instead of having two functions.